# Trouble Installing Ubuntu 14.04 on MacBook

Tags: 14.04, grub2, system-installation, macbook

So I had Ubuntu 14.04 installed on my Lenovo laptop. It worked perfectly but screen resolution was terrible so I wanted to use it on my old 2009 unibody MacBook. I transferred the SSD hard drive directly into the MacBook from the Lenovo and it booted with some issues, and the WiFi driver wasnt recognized, but other than that it seemed to work just fine.

To relieve those issues I decided to re-install Ubuntu 14.04 from a USB and the installation worked fined until I was asked to restart the computer at the end.

When I restarted the computer, it took me to the 'GNU GRUB version 2.02^beta2-9' menu screen which contains two options:

```
Ubuntu
Advanced options for Ubuntu
```

When I chose 'Ubuntu', the screen turns purple and doesnt change (Ive let it sit for hours).

When I chose 'Advanced options for Ubuntu', I receive the following options:

```
Ubuntu, with Linux 3.13.0-30-generic
Ubuntu, with Linux 3.13.0-30-generic (recovery mode)
Ubuntu, with Linux 3.13.0-24-generic
Ubuntu, with Linux 3.13.0-24-generic (recovery mode)
```

Choosing any of these four options also takes me to the infinite purple screen.

If I press 'e' when I am on the first 'GNU GRUB version 2.02^beta2-9' menu, it has the following:

```
setparams 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.13.0-13-generic'

            recordfail
            load_video
            gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
            insmod gzio
            insmod part_gpt
            insmod ext2
            set=root'hd1,gpt2'
            if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
              search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd1,gpt2 --hint-efi=hd1,gpt2 --hint -baremetal =ahci1,gpt2 xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx

            else
              search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx
            fi
            echo    'Loading Linux 3.13.0-30-generic ..'
            linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-30-generic.efi.signed root=UUID=xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx ro quiet splash $vt_handoff
            initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-30-generic
```

I am not sure what to do here. Do I need to change some of those parameters? My knowledge is not sufficient to troubleshoot on my own, and a web search has turned up nothing of use.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Where it says:

`quiet splash`

Change to:

```
nomodeset
```

Once you get to the desktop run a full update/upgrade using the software updater, and install the latest stable NVIDIA graphics driver from the `Additional Drivers` application.

That should get your mac up and running. Good luck!